# converting MATLAB code (bwdist(bw,'cityblock')) to python

Tags: python, matlab

I want to convert bwdist function of MATLAB to Python. As I searched, `scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt` can be similar to `D1 = bwdist(bw,'euclidean');`

but I didn't find any similar functions to these three lines of codes below:

```
D2 = bwdist(bw,'cityblock');
D3 = bwdist(bw,'chessboard');
D4 = bwdist(bw,'quasi-euclidean');
```

can anybody help me with these? I want to convert the above codes to Python.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify what these other measurements do? The city-block one is commonly called Manhattan distance, but I (and probably many of your readers) am unfamiliar with the other two.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/ndimage.html?highlight=scipy%20ndimage%20morphology#distance-transforms) says _"the function `distance_transform_cdt` can be used to more efficiently calculate city block and chessboard distance transforms"_ but I'm not familiar enough with it to say how to implement that in practice.